# Lock screen when unauthorized USB device plugged into Windows

Tags: windows, usb, forensics

I read an article about how Ross Ulbrich get caught.

Basically the FBI put an unauthorized USB that keeps his computer working. This is how they got a lot of evidences against Ulbrich.

There is a software to counter that

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USBKill

Basically any time someone enter an unauthorized USB devices, the software will go back to login screen.

Is there such software for windows? Any new USB devices need to be explicitly authorized by password?

Comment: Maybe this https://superuser.com/questions/689977/disable-usb-storage-access-on-non-admin-account